# Matching and parsing to extract information from complicated string

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string with the arguments from a function such as `'arg0, arg1=1, arg2=None'` and would like to extract the names and default values for each argument. I have no problems handling simple cases. The problem are strings, lists, and tuples as default arguments. Here is my current attempt

```
def get_args(s):
    regex = r'([a-zA-Z0-9._]*)\s*=?\s*(.*)'
    # save and replace quoted strings
    str_quoted = re.findall(r'([\"\'].*?[\"\'])', s)
    for quote in str_quoted:
        s = s.replace(quote, '%s')
    # split arguments
    args = re.split("[ ]{0,10},[ ]{0,10}", s)
    # restore quoted strings
    args = ('\n'.join(args) % tuple(str_quoted)).split('\n')
    # return arguments
    return [{
        'name': re.match(regex, arg).group(1),
        'def': re.match(regex, arg).group(2)
    } for arg in args]
```

And some example strings

```
s1 = 'arg0, arg1=1, arg2=None'
s2 = 'arg0, arg1=",", arg2=None'
s3 = 'arg0, arg1=[1, 2], arg2=[1, 2]'
s4 = 'arg0, arg1=(1, 2), arg2=(1, 2)'
s5 = 'arg0, arg1=[1, [1,2,3]], arg2=[1, 2]'
```

`get_args(s1)` works with this output (a list of dictionaries with the name of the argument and the default value)

```
[{'def': '', 'name': 'arg0'},
 {'def': '1', 'name': 'arg1'},
 {'def': 'None', 'name': 'arg2'}]
```

`s2` works as well but the others don't. My current solution for strings is to temporary replace them (see `str_quoted` part). I tried something similar for lists or tuples but quickly ran into problems.

Any suggestions for a `get_args` function that reliably separates the arguments from the default values?

Comment: This is not a problem you should solve with regular expressions. This is a parser type of problem.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Although you can use regex to lex.

Comment: @JoelCornett: Sure, regular expressions are a great tool to tokenize, but you'd still need to do more work after that to produce the desired output. May as well use a dedicated parsing library.

Comment: Is there a limit to how deep you want to nest these lists and tuples? If you're only going one (or 2 levels deep) you could probably roll your own regex/python combination. Otherwise, I'd do as Martinn says and look into a parser lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with. Martijn Pieters and some of the other posters are correct that a proper parser would be the right way to go. I opted for a simple iteration through the characters, which handles all the examples above, many more, and unlimited nesting. Maybe not as elegant but it does the job pretty well. Some special cases are still not addressed though (e.g. escape characters)

```
def get_args(s):
    # prepare
    syn = {'"': False, "'": False, '(': 0, '[': 0}
    mapping = {')': '(', ']': '['}
    args = []
    arg = {'name': '', 'def': ''}
    type = 'name'
    # iterate through chars
    for c in s:
        bracket = syn['('] == 0 and syn['['] == 0
        quote = (syn['"'] is True and c is not '"') or (syn["'"] is True and c is not "'")
        # add to argument definition
        if re.match(r"[a-zA-Z0-9._ ]", c) or quote:
            arg[type] += c
        # quotes
        elif re.match(r"[\"\']", c):
            syn[c] = not syn[c]
            arg[type] += c
        # brackets
        elif re.match(r"[\(\[]", c):
            syn[c] += 1
            arg[type] += c
        elif re.match(r"[\)\]]", c):
            syn[mapping[c]] -= 1
            arg[type] += c
        # '=' to define default value
        elif re.match(r"=", c) and bracket:
            type = 'def'
        # ',' to seperate arguments
        elif re.match(r",", c) and bracket:
            type = 'name'
            args.append({'name': arg['name'].strip(), 'def': arg['def'].strip()})
            arg = {'name': '', 'def': ''}
        else:
            arg[type] += c
    # add last arg
    if syn['('] == 0 and syn['['] == 0 and syn['"'] is False and syn["'"] is False:
        args.append({'name': arg['name'].strip(), 'def': arg['def'].strip()})
    # return
    return args
```

Answer (score 1):

append flower braces on either side of the string and do json.loads then you only have to deal with a dict. forget re.

```
arg_str = yourstring
arg_str = '{%s}' % arg_str
import json
dict_arg = json.loads(arg_str)
```

If you get errors it might be because that json will only accept double quotes and if your arguments have single quotes replace them and then load